# If JNDI can be serialised to the local JVM, why we need RMI to call method?

Tags: java, rmi, jndi

When I use JNDI to get an object from a remote server, the object can be serialised to the local JVM, this way I am assuming that we can call methods on this object locally without RMI, so why we need RMI?

Comment: RMI isn't always necessary. If you need it, it's because what you looked up was an RMI service. Plenty of JNDI lookups return other resources.

Answer (score 4):

[JNDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html) is a look-up and directory service. It provides a standardized way to acquire resources by name within some context. Usually it used for acquiring shared resources from an application-server context, but depending on implementation, it can also provide for looking up items in a standardized way that represent remote resources.

[RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) is a remote method invocation technology built-in to the Java platform. It allows for calling remote java object methods over a binary protocol. It uses Java's built-in serialization handling to make the remote invocation and parameter passing over the network seem transparent.  RMI requires it's own directory/look-up service that or might not be integrated with a given JNDI implementation.  (Usually they are not integrated.)

So, with all that in mind, hopefully you can see why your question isn't very clear.  You *might* look-up a remote RMI service via JNDI. You *might* be able to save (serialize) that remote RMI reference to disk and then reconstruct it to use it again later (although that is probably not a good idea.) But regardless, JNDI and RMI are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming that we can call methods on this object locally without
>   RMI

No,It is important to understand that you need two extra objects when you make a remote method invocation. The Stub which runs on the client side and de Skeleton which runs on the server side. These objects performs the necessary low level operations.

When the client invokes a remote method it never call directly the object, instead it uses the Stub object.

Therefore, what you get from JNDI service is the Stub not the remote object.

Comment: You haven't needed a skeleton since 1998.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use JNDI to get an object from a remote server, the object can be serialised to the local JVM, this way I am assuming that we can call methods on this object locally without RMI, so why we need RMI?

So you can call methods *remotely.* An object that has been deserialized into your local JVM executes in your JVM. A remote object executes in a remote JVM even though you called it from your local JVM.